# VBA CreateObject error in only one instance

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have a macro-enabled workbook I send to clients to do some light data processing, and at one point I have this code:

```
Dim dict as Object
set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

This has worked for most clients for many years, but a recently client said the workbook wasn't doing its thing, so I discovered it was bombint at this line with an `Object not found` error. I had them add the reference via the Tools menu to the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and then changed the line to

```
dict = new Dictionary
```

and then it ran fine.

But the weird thing is that there are multiple dictionaries used, all of them initialized with `CreateObject` yet it's only this one line that bombing. The workbook runs fine as-is on my computer, and on a colleague's computer. Versions of Excel amongst everyone is the same. I even made sure the client had saved the workbook to their desktop and not a protected Downloads folder, and that it didn't say "Compatibility Mode" when opened. So I'm about out of ideas as to why this is happening for this one client since I can't reproduce the error, but have tried to eliminate all the variables. It's not practical for me to tell every client user to add the runtime reference, hence the use of `CreateObject()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to use “Set” keyword : Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Comment: Are you 100% sure `dict` is declared `As Object`? The only way I can see a no-set assignment working is with `Dim dict` or `Dim dict As Variant`.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected that when I typed in the example. I have `Set` in my code. Again, it works for me and for many past clients, just this one dictionary for this one client. If I convert this one to using the `new Scripting.Dictionary` but leave the rest, it runs fine too, so it's not even the syntax that is a problem, just something hanging. Perhaps there's a race condition where the declaration isn't done quickly enough? But actually I tried making `dict` a global at the top of the module, and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Declarations aren't executable statements, it's not it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not practical for me to tell every client user to add the runtime reference". *Your* workbook would have the reference, not the clients'. That said, it might simply be a registry issue.  Try instantiating it from the clsid:  `Set dict = CreateObject("new:EE09B103-97E0-11CF-978F-00A02463E06F")`

Comment: So, there are many lines `... = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` in the workbook, and the only one of them, only on one PC isn't working? You may open the workbook without enabling macro in the dialog on the top, save the workbook and close it. Then open again as usual.

Comment: @Comintern References are set on the user's side via the VB Editor, they're not a per-file setting. That's why I'm using late binding (`... as Object`). Interested about your CSID idea though; how did you find out which one to use?

Comment: @redOctober13 No, references are per *project*, which makes them per file. Re the CLSID, I just popped scrrun.dll open in OLEView and pulled it from the TypeLib.

Comment: Can you post a link to the file?

Comment: I can't unfortunately, it's proprietary